# Autoload class file with namespace

Tags: php, class, spl-autoload-register

I try to refactor my code and use autoload system. For now, I'm doing:

index.php:

```
namespace example_com;
use example_com\Core\Application;
require 'Application.php';
$app = new Application();
$app->MyCustomFunction();
```

I would like to eliminate require line; I would like to require whenever I call new Application() or new Class();

I try like below:

index.php

```
namespace example_com;
use example_com\Core\Application;

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $namespace = str_replace("\\", "/", __NAMESPACE__);
    $className = str_replace("\\", "/", $className);
    $class = ROOT . (empty($namespace) ? "" : $namespace . "/") . "{$className}.php";
    include_once($class);
});

//require 'Application.php';//remove this
$app = new Application();
$app->MyCustomFunction();
```

Application.php

```
namespace example_com\Core;
class Application
{
    //..contruct, properties, functions
}
```

=DEBUG OUTOUT=

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) { //$className: "example_com/Core/Application"
    $namespace = str_replace("\\", "/", __NAMESPACE__); //$namespace: "example_com"
    $className = str_replace("\\", "/", $className);
    $class = ROOT . (empty($namespace) ? "" : $namespace . "/") . "{$className}.php"; //$className: "example_com/Core/Application" $namespace: "example_com" $class: "example_com/example_com/Core/Application.php"
```

I'm planning to use this in different files in the same project

UPDATE 1:
Folder Structure

```
App/
--Controllers/
----XController.php
----YController.php
Core/
--Controllers/
----IBaseController.php
----BaseController.php
--Application.php
index.php
```

Comment: Are all your classes in the same base folder? I would think you should have all your classes in the same folder so you could make one `spl_autoload_register()` that would load at the top of your page (perhaps in an included config-type file) and cover all of your classes through out your app? I don't think I would make an autoloader on a per-class basis. That may slow down you app a bit.

Comment: All my classes are not in the same folder. I edit topic which shows my folder structure

Answer (score 1):

To clarify my comment about in the same folder, your folder structure seems organized, I was just confirming that you didn't just have classes floating everywhere. I would implement just one autoloader after session or similar, looking in two spots *(see bottom example if in more spots)*:

In your config file:

```
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    # Set base path
    $default = ROOT.DS.'Core';
    # Set client/vendor path (provided "App" is the
    # name of the root containing vendor libraries)
    $app     = ROOT.DS.'App';
    # Create path
    $path    = str_replace('\\',DS,$class).'.php';
    # Check first that class exists in core
    if(is_file($inc = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,$default.DS.$path)))
        require_once($inc);
    # Check if the class is in the "App" folder
    elseif(is_file($inc = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,$app.DS.$path)))
        require_once($inc);
});
```

If there are more places (or "App" represents a pseudo class library name), I would use `json` file with paths to the directories:

**/Core/prefs/namespaces.json**

```
["NewFolder/Classes","OtherFolder/Somewhere/Deeper/Classes","Vendor/Classes"]
```

In your config file:

```
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $default = ROOT.DS.'Core';
    $app     = ROOT.DS.'App';
    $path    = str_replace('\\',DS,$class).'.php';

    if(is_file($inc = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,$default.DS.$path)))
        require_once($inc);
    elseif(is_file($inc = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,$app.DS.$path)))
        require_once($inc);
    # Here is where you will fetch the array of namespaces
    else {
        # Fetch and decode
        $namespaces = json_decode(file_get_contents(ROOT.DS.'Core'.DS.'prefs'.DS.'namespaces.json'),true);
        # Check to make sure there are namespaces to loop over
        if(is_array($namespaces) && !empty($namespaces)) {
            # Loop
            foreach($namespaces as $base) {
                # Check if the class file exists and include if it does
                if(is_file($inc = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,ROOT.DS.$base.DS.$path)))
                    require_once($inc);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the above instance, I would probably then work towards one or two folders that host either all vendor libraries (including your `Core` library) or two that can be searched so a `Core` and a `Vendor` folder.